# We have vs We do have

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-difference, phrases

What is the difference between

> **We have**

and

> **We do have**?

Has it same meaning or different meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In positive statements the use of the auxiliary *do* is always optional, and it conveys emphasis (usually contrastive).

The basic objective meaning of the statement is unchanged, but emphatic *do* adds a connotation of "contrary to what you thought/you asked/I suggested/somebody said".

Examples of emphatic *do*:

> Have you any coffee? No, but we do have hot chocolate.
>
> Have you any coffee? I don't think so, but I'll check. Yes, we **do** have some!
>
> We haven't got a golf course here,  but we do have a pool with a waterslide.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`We do have` has more weight to it. `Do` before a verb is often used for adding emphasis.

Comment: but meaning is same. Am i correct?

Comment: They refer to the same objective circumstances. But pragmatic meaning is part of meaning, and in that sense they are differnet.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is the same but the two constructions are typically used in different contexts.

**We have.....** is a simple statement of whatever items someone may have to offer. If a customer were to ask a greengrocer what fresh products were available, the latter might reply: **We have lettuce that just in, freshly picked cabbage, newly delivered cauliflower....and so on.

However, if a customer were to walk into a shop looking for a specific product, say a replacement alternator for a car, the salesperson might reply:

> Well, we do have one in stock but it's not brand new. It comes from a newish car that was written off in an accident.

The construction **we do have....** is typically followed by some comment or condition or limitation that might affect the sale.

Equally, a headmaster might tell a parent looking for a place for a child:

> We do have one more place but it's supported by a bursary, which means that your child will have to meet certain conditions.

Comment: thank you so much